# goog:chromeOptions being ignored completely using RSpec, Capybara, and Selenium

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara

Is anyone else having this problem?  It seems that somewhere `goog:chromeOptions` are not getting passed to `chromedriver` properly - which results in Chrome just opening with default options.

I'm using the following Capybara/Selenium configuration:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
      args: %w[ start-maximized ]
    }
  )

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: capabilities,
    driver_opts: {
      log_path: "./tmp/chrome#{Time.now.to_i}.log",
      verbose: true
    }
  )
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

However, when I open up the Capybara session log, the `goog:chromeOptions` have not been set at all.  Is this why my Chrome window is not maximized?

Session log:

```
[1550680994.143][INFO]: COMMAND InitSession {
   "capabilities": {
      "firstMatch": [ {
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
           //nothing is here???  should have args!
         }
      } ]
   },
   "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "cssSelectorsEnabled": true,
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
        //nothing is here???  should have args!
      },
      "javascriptEnabled": true,
      "nativeEvents": false,
      "platform": "ANY",
      "rotatable": false,
      "takesScreenshot": false,
      "version": ""
   }
}
```

Operating System:

Ubuntu 18.04

My environment:

```
ruby 2.6.1
capybara (2.18.0)
selenium-webdriver (3.13.0)
ChromeDriver 2.37.544315
```

Everytime I run a Selenium test, the window is not maximized.  But this isn't another "the screen isn't maximized" post (there are lots of those already).  This appears to be an issue where my options are not being parsed properly perhaps?  I don't get whats wrong.  I'm following all the README's and guides as best I can.  Its just not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by upgrading Capybara and Selenium Webdriver!

```
capybara (3.13.2)
selenium-webdriver (3.141.0)
```

Now the debug log has what I was expecting to see:

```
[1550686685.534][INFO]: COMMAND InitSession {
   "capabilities": {
      "firstMatch": [ {
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "args": [ "start-maximized" ]
         }
      } ]
   },
   "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "cssSelectorsEnabled": true,
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
         "args": [ "start-maximized" ]
      },
      "javascriptEnabled": true,
      "nativeEvents": false,
      "platform": "ANY",
      "rotatable": false,
      "takesScreenshot": false,
      "version": ""
   }
}
```